# New to Git: git push origin master = "ssh_exchange_identifiction: Connection closed by remote host. Fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying out git for the first time and am trying to follow instructions supplied by github.  However, I seem to be failing on the last step.  The following steps are provided by github:

```
Global setup:

  Download and install Git
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
  git config --global user.email 


Next steps:

  mkdir SomeFolder
  cd SomeFolder
  git init
  touch README
  git add README
  git commit -m 'first commit'
  git remote add origin git@github.com:username/SomeFolder.git
  git push origin master
```

However, when running the final command, git push origin master, I get

> "ssh_exchange_identification: 
>   Connection closed by remote host. 
>   fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly"

Why might this be?

Answer (score 7):

GitHub is highly secured and follow ssh-rsa
So we need to setup as ssh public key for our connection, and let github know about it.

take terminal and as user ( not root, usually many of us have a habit of typing sudo su as the first commang at terminal, this time avoid it)
type

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "yourmailid@gmail.com"
```

Here,
         -t -> tells which encryption
         -C ->try to use the same mail id you have given ti github (for ease of memory)

now you will get two files
id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in ~/.ssh/

now copy the whole content in file id_rsa.pub without altering the content of the file.

Now go back to you github account.
go to account settings >>> SSH Public Keys
Add a new Key
and paste the content you copied into field "key" and save (give a title of your choice).

now github know to process the requests from your system.

now try

```
$ssh git@github.com
```

thuis must return Hi! UserName
ignore if any error is shown,
but make sure , it shows Hi! UserName

okay! now we are going to set the repositories local copy on ouor machine and reflect changes at the remote system

make a directory ( as user, not root )

```
mkdir MyProject
cd MyProject

git init
```

( initialise an empty git repository there, see for a hidden folder .git/ there.)
after creating files in MyProjects, when you feel like adding it to your repository at github, do

```
git add
```

now run status and check the files you are going to commit next,

```
git status

git commit -m "Your comment about this commit"
```

( this updates .git/ folder in your local repository )
now we tell git about the remote repository to be updated

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/ProjectName
```

( you remember from where we got this URL, its Your Clone URL )

```
git push origin master
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

did you add your RSA key with ssh-add?

ssh-add your-rsa-key

Comment: running this, i get "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Comment: you must be running ssh-agent to use ssh-add, but it seems that this is not the problem, it would produce different error

Answer (score 0):

The SSH key on your machine doesn't match the one that you have on record with GitHub. Type

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

which will copy your public key to the clibboard. Then go to GitHub account settings and add it as a new key.

Comment: That command did not seem to work for me.  However, i manually went to my .ssh.pub file and copy/pasted it to the github account settings.  Still no dice.

Comment: pbcopy is a Mac OS only command, you can use `xclip -selection c` instead of pbcopy on Linux.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I assumed Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Some times you must run:

```
git pull
```

Be carefull! Backup your repo folder before run this command.

Comment: Looks more like the asker has a brand-new repo.  There's nothing to pull.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you may reinitialize the connection to github by just running push command again:

```
git push -u origin master
```

It seems to have worked !